# how do i fix my problem with live update in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have to rebuild the project even if i modify a simple string in a Text composable. i tried changing dependencies related to Preview but it still is not working. any solution?
these are  the dependencies that i have :

```
 implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
```

Comment: i updated android studio and that solved the problem